# Two threads working on shared data

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two threads, called `Fun` and `Boring`.  Each thread takes the same read-only data and runs some calculations over it and returns a `[0.0, 1.0]` result.

In the current setup, `Fun` acts as the main thread.  It gathers, prepares, and stores the data in a global variable; a memory barrier is used.  It then signals (via an event) the `Boring` thread that there is data to work on.  `Fun` and `Boring` now both operate on the data.

Here is code which illustrates the set up:

```
struct Data
{
    void*   someData;
} g_data;

struct Results
{
    float fun;
    float boring;
} g_results;

Fun::Run()
{
    g_data = somePointer;   // Prepare data
    // *memory barrier*

    SetEvent(dataIsPrepared);
        g_results.fun = FunCalculate(g_data);
    WaitForSingleObject(boringComplete);

    // Do something with g_results
}

Boring::Run()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(dataIsPrepared);
        g_results.boring = BoringCalculate(g_data);
        // *memory barrier*
    SetEvent(boringComplete);
}
```

Is there a "better" way to share data and results?  Are there any red flags that stand out?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct code. It could go into production.

You don't need the memory barrier because SetEvent will do that for you (if it didn't a *lot* of code would be broken).

You could change this to use futures (provided that you have some C++ lib that supports them. I don't really know C++ well):

```
var data = PrepareData();
var boringComputation = StartSomeFuture([&data] { ... });
var funComputation = ComputeFun(data);
var boringResult = boringComputation.ResultAndWait();
```

Much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Now that we got that out of the way, there is always a "better way" than using hand-coded synchronization, especially since what you are doing is in fact a producer-consumer pattern.

You can use for example Intel TBB which has some nice concurrent queue data structures (for example [concurrent_bounded_queue](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00129.html)) in order to easily share data between a producer and a consumer in a thread-safe manner.